# Can I select features which are a split-up of the target variable for a regression model?

Tags: regression, python, feature-selection, feature-engineering

I'm currently working on predicting the energy consumption of a house (in KWH). After preprocessing the dataset, I used XGBRegressor to find the importance of features (feature importance method). The following features got the highest importance - energy consumption of AC (in KWH), energy consumption of other appliances (in KWH), energy consumption of heater (in KWH) and multiple other features. They basically add up to the target variable.

Total energy consumption -  energy consumption of AC (in KWH) + energy consumption of other appliances (in KWH) + energy consumption of heater (in KWH).

Note - This is a non linear data (Failed linear regression assumptions). So I'm using a tree based regression.

Is it correct to use these features for the model or is it wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! // 1) How do you have the components that add up to the target yet fail the linearity assumption of linear regression? 2) Will you have access to those measurements when it comes time to calculate total energy consumption?

Comment: As is often the case, it depends on what you want to do. It's not terribly *interesting* to predict the total energy usage from individual categories (taking the sum is trivial and requires no machine learning), but it's not technically *wrong*. The bigger question is why are you building this model and what predictor features will you actually have access to - I can't imagine a situation where you'd know the energy consumption of each appliance category but not for the whole house.

Comment: @Dave 1) I used the lasso regression algorithm to fit the baseline model (due to multicollinearity- found usign VIF) and plotted the residual vs fits plot. It plot was a perfect curve suggesting non-linear data. There are 900 features in total.
2) I honestly don't have an answer to the 2nd question. Let's assume I don't have access to these variables in real world. What should I do then?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie You make total sense. Let's assume we don't have those variables in real world. So it's better to ignore those variables right?

Comment: @Sudhandar Right, it would be statistically valid to build such a model, but it wouldn't be very useful to build a model that relies on data you don't actually expect to have - you'd be building a model that would be impossible to apply in practice.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie Great, thank you so much for your inputs.